# Weird Color Change on Linux Mint under VirtualBox

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, cinnamon

Currently I have a machine that runs Linux Mint 18.1, drivers and vbox additions up-to date.

Everytime I started the machine, the background image turns into a weird colorish image.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

After some background changes it becomes normal.
[image]

However I don't want to change background everytime I open the machine.

Answer (score 2):

This command fixed this issue for me:

gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin background-transition fade-in

To be executed in the guest Linux Mint OS.

Comment: Still works almost a year later  - guessing it's related to the guest additions and 3D acceleration (a bug), but this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I get this too. The gamma is way too high, initially.

There seems to be another problem associated with VirtualBox, the latest Guest Additions, and 3D acceleration mode. Maybe they're related...